# I don't understand value iteration

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

In class I am learning about value iteration and markov decision problems, we are doing through the UC Berkley pac-man project, so I am trying to write the value iterator for it and as I understand it, value iteration is that for each iteration you are visiting every state, and then tracking to a terminal state to get its value.

I have a feeling I am not right, because when I try that in python I get a recursive depth exceed. So I return to the pseudo-code, and there is a `Vk[s]` and `Vk-1[s']`, which I had thought to mean value of state, and value of `newState`, but I must be missing something.

So what is the significance of the `k` and `k-1`?

My Code:

```
 def val(i, state):
        if mdp.isTerminal(state) or i == 0:
            return 0.0
        actionCost = {}
        for action in mdp.getPossibleActions(state):
            actionCost[action] = 0
            for (nextState, probability) in mdp.getTransitionStatesAndProbs(state, action):
                reward = mdp.getReward(state, action, nextState)
                actionCost[action] += probability * reward + discount * val(i - 1, nextState)        
        return actionCost[max(actionCost, key=actionCost.get)]

    for i in range(iterations):
        for state in mdp.getStates():  
            self.values[state] = val(i, state)
```

Pseudo Code:

```
k ←0 
repeat
      k ←k+1 
      for each state s do 
          Vk[s] = maxa ∑s' P(s'|s,a) (R(s,a,s')+ γVk-1[s']) 
until ∀s |Vk[s]-Vk-1[s]| < θ
```

Comment: You can extend the recursion depth in python http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit to see if it helps.

Comment: Vk(s) is the expected value (could be seen as a potential) of state s if you look down k steps with an optimal policy

Comment: Your could will lookdown one step further until it converges below theta

Comment: I don't see any problems with the pseudo code so perhaps you can include more? What happens if you increase theta?
Whats the printout for max(Vk[s] for s in states) foreach iteration? (does it iterate over k atleast ones?) What is the stop condition for the recursion (V0)

Comment: There is no error in the pseudo code, it's that I don't understand all of it. I dont know what theta is, though I imagine it is floating around somewhere in the code given to the class. I've included my code so you can see how I did it. My while loop doesn't track any theta, it stops when the k is up.

Comment: looked through your code a couple of times but couldn't find anything major except for probability * reward + discount * val(i - 1, nextState) should be probability * (reward + discount * val(i - 1, nextState)), but it should still run

Comment: Additionally ``for i in range(iteration):`` will have the same result as just setting ``i=iteration``. It reminds of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDA* <--(the star is missing in the link for some reason)

Comment: Theta is just a value that tells the algorithm when the V converges. For each additional steps the algorithm (foreach higher start k) generates a better approximation of the V_(k=infinit) and if the difference from the last run is smaller than the threshold (theta).

Comment: Did my explanations clarify things?

Comment: And you have  problem with parens in your expression (compare the pseudocode and your code)

Comment: Your first paragraph is a single run-on sentence. Better writing might lead to better answers.

Answer (score 2):

Vk and Vk-1 are different iterations of the approximation of V. You could rewrite the pseudo code as:

```
V ← 0
V' ← 0
while true
  for each state s do
      V ← V'
      V = maxa ∑s' [ P(s'|s,a) R(s,a,s')+ γV'[s'] ]
  if ∀s |V[s]-V'[s]| < θ
      return V
```

Note that the pseudo-code is not recursive. This is the idea of value-iteration/dyanmic-programming which make it efficient :

- Compute the optimal value function for 0 time step: V0=0
- *then* compute the optimal value function for 1 time step: V1=H(V0)
- *then* compute the optimal value function for 2 time steps: V2=H(V1)
- *then* compute the optimal value function for 3 time steps: V3=H(V2)
- ...
- *then* compute the optimal value function for n time steps: Vn=H(Vn-1)

with H defined as:

```
 H(V) = max_a ( Pa [ Ra + γ V ] )
```

Your code is recursive (val calls val) which triggers some stack overflow error. Value iteration is not recursive but iterative. Your 'eval' function make this:

```
actionCost[action] += probability * reward + discount * val(i - 1, nextState)
```

which recomputes recursively a values that you have already computed at the previous iteration (k-1). val(i - 1, nextState) is in fact:

```
 self.previous_values[nextState]
```

(assuming you keep a copy of previousValue).